# Problem with mord library function 'Logistic AT'

Tags: python, nlp

I wanted to run a an ordinal logistic regression on my bag of words. I have used the code below with logistic regression but now I have modified it for an ordinal logistic regression. However, when I try to predict Y, I keep getting the error:

```py
AttributeError: 'LogisticAT' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I am pretty sure the error is in the following line, but not sure how to fix it.

```py
ml_model = LogisticAT(alpha = 1.0)
```

```py
def train_logisticAT_regression(features, label):
    print ("Training the logistic regression model...")
    from mord import LogisticIT, LogisticAT, OrdinalRidge
    ml_model = LogisticAT(alpha = 1.0)
    print ('Finished')
    return ml_model

ml_model = train_logisticAT_regression(tfidf_features, y_train)

test_data_features = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
# Convert to numpy array
test_data_features = test_data_features.toarray()

test_data_tfidf_features = tfidf.fit_transform(test_data_features)
# Convert to numpy array
test_data_tfidf_features = test_data_tfidf_features.toarray()

predicted_y = ml_model.predict(test_data_tfidf_features)
```

I'm not familiar with the mord package. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you did not train the model.

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/mord/) you can find the documentation. However, just look at your function (and possibly put the import statements outside of it), you never use `label` variable.

You want to add the instruction

```py
ml_model.fit(features, label)
```

before the return statement.

After that, you never call `fit_transform` on test data, only `transform`.